# getting typescript to work with visual studio 2015 rc?

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

trying to code angularjs in typescript in vs 2015 rc

- after install web essential, there is not side by side typescript and javascript pane anymore
- after adding angularjs definite type nu-get package, can't get IntelliSense for 'angular'

anything wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get IntelliSense for 'angular' you need also to include a reference to the DefinitelyTyped package in your file:

```
/// <reference path="angular.d.ts" />'
```

Check the README that came with the package, or this link for further reading: https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/angularjs